# With Semantic UI React, how to build a tag input similar to Stack Overflow's?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm interested in building a Tag input feature like Stack Overflow where the feature set includes:

1. Input field which has a autocomplete feature (takes user input, fetches results from the server and displays those results to the user for easy selection.
2. Input field contains 1 or more selected items as tags.
3. Suggestions outside of the input which when clicked have the results added to the input field.

Screenshots from Stack Overflow:

[image]
[image]

I'm using Semantic-UI-React and notice there is a search component which could work: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search

It does not appear that this Semantic-UI-React search component allows for adding more than one result or adding results via a method outside of the input. Am I missing something?

Should I use Semantic UI for this feature or will I need to build this entirely from scratch in my React app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not properly highlighted in the react semantic-ui dropdown documentation but the *allowAdditions* field will enable tagging capabilities:

```
<Dropdown search selection multiple allowAdditions />
```

Comment: I'm trying this in https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-selection and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @David can you put up a fiddle so I can give it a look?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `onAddItem` prop to update the options list. In [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-selection), I did this:

`<Dropdown
    placeholder='Select Friend'
    fluid
    search
    selection
    multiple
    allowAdditions
    onAddItem={(event, data) => friendOptions.push({key: data.value, text: data.value, value: data.value})}
    options={friendOptions}
  />`

And now you can add items to the dropdown list.